# Splitting of XML File

Tags: xml, cmd, split, tags, treeview

I am trying to split the XML file of one line into multiple lines using cmd, can someone assist me in this. For example

**Input:**

```
<ns2:requestor><name>OBSS_PROCESS</name><correlationId>fe5eb119-d8d6-45b9-b493-759f21baf0d7</correlationId><dateTime>2022-01-07T15:49:37.792-06:00</dateTime></ns2:requestor><ns2:customerIdentifier>DG</ns2:customerIdentifier>
```

**Output:**

```
<ns2:requestor>
<name>OBSS_PROCESS</name>
<correlationId>fe5eb119-d8d6-45b9-b493-759f21baf0d7</correlationId>
<dateTime>2022-01-07T15:49:37.792-06:00</dateTime>
</ns2:requestor>
<ns2:customerIdentifier>DG</ns2:customerIdentifier>
```

I have tried one of the Unix commands and changed it into windows, but I think that's not enough

repl 's/><[^/]/>\n</g' test.xml

Comment: cmd or Powershell? Pick one, they are not the same thing. Also, what's the question? Where is your code? Stack Overflow is not your code writing service. Show code you wrote, ask a question about it.

Comment: @Tomalak

CMD or Powershell both works fine for me, but preferably cmd.

Comment: The provided XML is not well-formed on two counts: (1) missing root tag, (2) no  **ns2** namespace declaration. So it is not an XML file,

Answer (score 0):

As a simplistic process that will produce what you stated as the goal, you could use this .bat file run in `cmd`. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell is available. Taking @Mofi's comment and finding a proper tool might be a better idea.

=== afile.bat

```
@powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$(Get-Content -Path '.\afile.xml') -replace '(</.*?>)', ('$1'+\"`n\")"
```

Execution example:

```
C:>afile.bat
<ns2:requestor><name>OBSS_PROCESS</name>
<correlationId>fe5eb119-d8d6-45b9-b493-759f21baf0d7</correlationId>
<dateTime>2022-01-07T15:49:37.792-06:00</dateTime>
</ns2:requestor>
<ns2:customerIdentifier>DG</ns2:customerIdentifier>
```

**UPDATE:**

This has not had much testing and does not do much error checking, but it might do what you want. Specify the .xml filename as the parameter on the command line.

=== afile.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "THEFILE=%~1"
IF "%THEFILE%" == "" (
    ECHO "usage: %0 <xmlfilename>"
) ELSE (
    COPY "%THEFILE%" "%THEFILE%.backup" >NUL
    @powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
        "$s = Get-Content -Path "%THEFILE%";" ^
        "$s -replace '(</.*?>)', ('$1'+\"`n\")" ^| Out-File -FilePath "%THEFILE%" -Encoding ascii"
)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The `afile.bat` script is designed to work on one (1) .xml file. The .xml filename is specified as a parameter on the command line. Note that `C:>` is the command line prompt and is not part of the command.

```
C:>afile.bat afile.xml
```

After this command is run, the `afile.xml` file will have been copied to `afile.xml.backup` and the modified content will be in `afile.xml`.

If you want to run afile.bat on all files in a directory, you could use  a `FOR` loop.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('DIR /B "*.xml"') DO ("afile.bat" "%~A")
```

If the FOR loop is placed into a .bat file script, the loop variables must have the PERCENT SIGN character doubled.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /B "*.xml"') DO ("afile.bat" "%%~A")
```

Comment: Your answer worked absolutely fine one more request over here can we edit and save the same file withholding the above command.

Comment: @Sheikh_Sheharyar, please see the update section.

Comment: this updated part is not working or maybe I am might not executing it properly could, would you please assist me a bit.

Comment: Can you say more about "not working?" Is there an error message? In what way is the output not correct?

Comment: On Executing the command i am having the following output
"usage: a.bat <xmlfilename>"

Comment: Please specify the .xml filename as the parameter on the command line. `afile.bat afile.xml` This will create a copy of the original file as `afile.xml.backup` and write the new content into `afile.xml`.

Comment: Ok @lit we have a situation over here as i modified your previous command that runs for all XML files in a directory which works absolutely fine

@powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$(Get-Content -Path '.\*.xml') -replace '(</.*?>)', ('$1'+\"`n\")"

Concern over here in which specific line i am supposed to add \.xml as parameter

Comment: The "Update" section is a .bat file script. It works on one (1) .xml file. The .xml filename is specified as the first parameter on the command line.

Comment: I would not change the -Path parameter to '*.xml'. See the UPDATE 2 section.